# Which process changes my configuration?

Tags: systemd, routing, systemctl

I have a systemctl service with `ip route add`, `ifconfig`, `arp` and `ethtool` commands to configure dynamically 2 interfaces.
Somehow, after some seconds/minutes or randomly, the configuration just disappeared (IPs not assigned anymore, routes and arp entries disappear).

**How can I debug this and why my settings disappeared?**

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/routingsf.sh enp4s0f0 enp4s0f1

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

I have lots of sh*** processes such as `Avahi-daemon` that send packets to broadcast even tho I don't want to.
These interfaces are used for testing purposes and I don't want undesired packets being sent through these interfaces.

Comment: If you run `nmcli device status`, what does it say? (You'll want it to say `unmanaged` for your `enp4s0f0` and `enp4s0f1` interfaces.)

Comment: Both are disconnected: `enp4s0f0    ethernet  disconnected  -- `. These interfaces are 10G SFP interfaces and are used for hardware testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nmcli device status` has `disconnected`  in the `STATE` column for your `enp4s0f0` and `enp4s0f1` interfaces, that means NetworkManager is assuming control of them.

Please run the following commands as root:

```
nmcli device set enp4s0f0 managed no
nmcli device set enp4s0f1 managed no
```

to tell NetworkManager to keep its hands off those devices. That should fix your problem. Usually NetworkManager should store these settings automatically so that they'll persist over a reboot, but this might depend on the Linux distribution you're using.

After this, `nmcli device status` should show the state of these network interfaces as `unmanaged`, indicating that you'll be free to configure these manually without any interference from NetworkManager.

---

And a nitpick on your systemd service: if your `routingsf.sh` does not include anything that keeps running forever, but just "set once and done"-type commands like `ip route add`, `ifconfig`, `arp` and `ethtool`, you might want to add two lines to the `[Service]` section of your service file:

```
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

If you don't specify a service type, systemd will assume `Type=simple`, which means that the process started with `ExecStart=` is expected to run forever until deliberately stopped. If your `routingsf.sh` does not do that, systemd will notice that your ExecStart command exits, and marks the service as failed.

The combination of `Type=oneshot` + `RemainAfterExit=yes` tells systemd that your script is expected to do some things and then exit, and that systemd should show the state of your service as "running" if the script exited successfully. You'll then have an option to add a corresponding `ExecStop=` option, if you want an easy way to toggle these settings off and on using the standard `systemctl` command.

Comment: Perfect full answer. I set up everything you said and it seems I need to learn more the `NetworkManager`. I use `Centos 7`. Thanks!

Comment: On RHEL/CentOS, RedHat has developed a fully read/write  capable NetworkManager configuration backend that uses the familiar `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files for network configuration. Other distributions have made different choices: e.g. Debian has a *read-only* configuration backend for their traditional `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and any new settings will be stored using NetworkManager's native configuration style in ` /etc/NetworkManager/*`. You should keep this in mind when reading NetworkManager instructions that are not specific to your distribution.

Comment: Various desktop environments may also plug in a NetworkManager configuration backend for *per-user* network configuration.

Comment: Understood, I'll be careful then. Thank you!